# Docker: bind mounts not working as I expected

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Most of the times I use Docker with volumes. But Now I am trying bind mounts for the first time and they are not working as I expected. I'm probably missing something or maybe not understanding completely they way they work.

Let's take this example. I have a React app created with `create-react-app` and it will run with a Rails backend based on a MySQL database.

My directory structure is:

```
App
├── docker
│   ├── api
│   │   └── Dockerfile
│   └── fe
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── package-lock.json
│       ├── public
│       ├── README.md
│       └── src
├── docker-compose.yml
```

I started by creating the `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  web:
    build: ./docker/fe/.
    ports: ["80:3000"]
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: "./docker/fe"
        target: "/app"
```

As you may see, I am mapping the directory `./docker/fe`, where the React frontend is, to `/app`.

Inside `./docker/fe` is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I was expecting this to work, because my app files are all inside `/app`, mapped to `./docker/fe`. At least I thought they would be! But when I run the `docker-compose up --build` command at the command line I get a build error, because it says there is no `package.json` file inside the `/app` directory.

On the other hand, when I use this other version of `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /app

ADD package.json .

ADD package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

ADD . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

this problem won't happen. It will find the `package.json` file and build the app correctly. But it won't run!

The fact is, it will say it can't find the React scripts. And it is no surprise, since when it is finished there is no `node_modules` directory inside `./docker/fe` as it would be expected after running `npm install`.

I am confused.

- Am I missing something about the bind mounts?
- Why do I need to ADD `package.json` to the WORKDIR if this directory is associated with the host directory where this file already is?
- Why I don't have a `node_modules` directory inside `./docker/fe` after `npm install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker volumes are only mounted when image is **run**, not during **build** phase.

Add these back in to your Dockerfile:

```
ADD package.json .

ADD package-lock.json .
```

And/or:

```
ADD . .
```

Comment: So, I must run `npm install` in the `./docker/fe` directory before running `docker-compose up --build`?

Comment: Your files weren't being mounted before, adding them back to your Dockerfile will make them available in the build context.  `WORKDIR` is only applicable inside the Docker image.  Check this out:
https://blog.codeship.com/using-docker-compose-for-nodejs-development/